# Solving for the firing rate of a model neuron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, computational-physics, integration, biophysics

I'm trying to decipher Figure 15.2A on page 442 of [this book chapter](http://nba.uth.tmc.edu/homepage/cnjclub/2007summer/renart_chapter.pdf).  It plots the firing rate $\nu$ of a model neuron against its mean current $\mu_c$.

The equation used to calculate the firing rate is

$$
\frac{1}{\nu} = \tau_{ref} + \tau_m\sqrt{\pi}\int_\frac{V_r - V_{ss}}{\sigma_V}^\frac{V_{th} - V_{ss}}{\sigma_V}{e^{x^2}(1 + erf(x))dx}.
$$

Here, $\tau_{ref} = 2$ms, $\tau_m = 10$ms, $V_{th}=-50$mV, $V_r=-60$mV, and $\sigma_V$ can be any of 0.1mV, 1mV, and 4 mV.

$V_{ss}$ is elsewhere in the chapter defined as $V_L+\mu_c/g_L$.  For this figure, $g_L=20$nS, $V_L=-70$mV, and $\mu_c$ ranges between 0.3 and 0.5nA.

According to the figure, any of the three values for $\sigma_V$ should produce a firing rate $\nu$ of ~80Hz when $\mu_c$ is 0.5nA.

However, when I compute the result numerically, I get for $\nu$ a value too large to be represented in my computer when $\sigma_V$ is 0.1mV, ~300Hz when $\sigma_V$ is 1mV, and ~80Hz only when $\sigma_V$ is 4mV.  None of the lines I get when plotting across different values of $\mu_c$ match those in the original figure.

Can anyone else replicate this figure?  Am I misinterpreting the integral?  Are there any obvious problems with the form of this equation that I'm missing?

**EDIT**: I've noticed that in this chapter the error function is defined as

$$
erf(x) = 2/\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^xe^{u^2}du.
$$

That is, the power of $e$ is $u^2$, not the usual $-u^2$.  I'm not sure whether this is a typo.  When I use what's written in the paper, my result is even farther off the mark than when I use the error function I'm used to seeing.

Comment: Please note that [check-my-work questions are generally considered off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind fair enough.  i guess you guys can close this if you'd like to.  do you have any suggestions for editing this to make it on-topic?  i guess i could just remove that initial statement in bold.  i was thinking that would make my question more appealing to people by making it seem easier to answer.

Comment: Do you want to compute the integral?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif yeah, that's what's causing me trouble.

Comment: Seeing as how the author refers to $\sigma_V$ as the "effective standard deviation in the voltage", and seeing as how yes, $\mathrm{erf}(x)=c \int e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u$. I'd guess that it should be $\int e^{-x^2}(1+\mathrm{erf}(x))\mathrm{d}x$. It could be a typesetting issue because that seems like too big of an error.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy that's a good guess, but your suggested change produces results even further from those reported in the paper.  it might be worth noting that the integral is written the same way as in this paper in a previous paper -- brunel & hakim '99 -- cited in this one.  (in that earlier paper, erf is included but not defined.)

Comment: @dbliss oh. Well then maybe Oussama's use of erfi is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ denote our integral:

$$
I=\int{{e}^{x^2}(1+erfi(x))} dx
$$

Using IBP:

$$
u=(1+erfi(x))\quad dv={e}^{x^2}dx\\
du=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} {e}^{x^2}dx \quad v=erfi(x)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$

You get:

$$
I=(1+erfi(x))erfi(x)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int{erfi(x) {e}^{x^2}dx}\\
I=(1+erfi(x))erfi(x)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int{erfi(x){e}^{x^2}-{e}^{x^2}dx} +\int{{e}^{x^2}dx}\\
I=(1+erfi(x))erfi(x)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-I+\int{{e}^{x^2}dx}\\
2I=(1+erfi(x))erfi(x)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}erfi(x)+C\\
I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}erfi(x)(2+erfi(x)) +C
$$

Now all you do is subsitute the values.

Comment: many thanks!  but how do i deal with `C`?

Comment: @dbliss I used the definition of the $erf(x)$ mentionned in the book but actually the real definition is the one mentionned in the comments

Comment: @dbliss it will cancel out when calculating the definite integral. You know that: $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}=F(a)-F(b)$ So there's no need for the constant

Comment: gotcha, thanks.  OK.  it does seem that that's a typo in the definition of erf in the book.  do you mind updating your answer so that it uses the correct definition of erf?  you might keep two versions of your answer, one for each version of erf.

Comment: @dbliss it doesnt matter since its just a name but when calculating the "erf" watch out as you would want to calculate $erfi(x)$ instead. Just use wolfram alpha for numerical application and make sure to use $erfi(x)$

Comment: why erfi?  (when i substitute erfi in for erf in my numerical computation using python, i get a result farther off than i was getting using erf.  but that's when i'm letting python compute the integral, not using the integral you got to analytically.)

Comment: Well because that's the actual definition otherwise it would be wrong.

Comment: i think you're saying that the definition provided in the paper is the definition of erfi, not erf.  but what i'm saying is that i think that definition includes a typo.  i think the authors intended to provide the normal definition of erf -- not erfi.

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: OK.  so in that case i would need to change your answer to fit the fact that erf was intended, not erfi.  right?  i'm not sure how exactly to do that.

Comment: Just update your question using $erfi$ and I'll update mine dont worry.

Comment: i don't want erfi -- i want erf.  the situation is stated at the bottom of my question (and throughout these comments).  i'm not sure why this confusion is persisting . . . let's take this to chat if you have any more questions about what's needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27584/discussion-between-oussama-boussif-and-dbliss).

Comment: my confidence that erf, not erfi, is intended has grown.  and i've worked out why i was getting weird results.  see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32303006/2623899).

Comment: @dbliss Okay because yesterday I was working on that hypergeomtric function that gave me a sum that I worked out using ODE and it gives a solution including erf